# Python: Nested if SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open("netlib.txt") as f1, open("mkl.txt") as f2, open("summary.txt", "w") as out:
for x, y in zip(f1, f2):
    if x.strip() == y.strip():
        out.write(x.strip() + "\n")
        if "Loops" in x:
            out.write("{0:<20}".format("Netlib") + "{0:<20}".format("MKL")   
    elif "@" in x and "@" in y:
            ...
```

I get this Error Message:

```
File "file_join.py", line 7
  elif ("@" in x and "@" in y):
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I comment out the 2 lines above the elif, it works fine.

Can someone please help?

Comment: `out.write(`... `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
            out.write("{0:<20}".format("Netlib") + "{0:<20}".format("MKL")
```

You're missing a close paren at the end. It should be:

```
            out.write("{0:<20}".format("Netlib") + "{0:<20}".format("MKL"))
```

Generally, if you get syntax errors when your code is valid, it's either due to the line above or due to bad indentation.